# Rigorous development of a continuous distributional basis for $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, distribution-theory, control-theory, dirac-delta

In control and signal processing, it's well-known that the impulse response (forcing by $\delta(t)$) of a linear time-invariant system completely determines its behavior. In discrete time the argument proceeds by constructing a basis of the discrete delta functions

$$
\delta(n-m) = \begin{cases}
1, \ \ n = m\\
0, \ \ n \neq m\\
\end{cases},
$$

and observing that an arbitrary signal $u(n)$ has the trivial reconstruction
$$
u(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty u(m)\delta(n-m).
$$
This in turn allows the system transfer function $H$ (which maps $\ell^2$ into itself) to act on the basis rather than the coefficients. Since the output $y(n)$ is related to the input $u(n)$ via $y(n) = Hu(n)$, by defining impulse response $h(n) = H\delta(n)$ we obtain
$$
y(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty u(m)h(n-m).
$$
Since $u(n)$ is arbitrary, all system specific information (e.g. BIBO stability) can be deduced from $h(n)$.

Speaking informally, the continuous time analog should be obtained by reducing $\delta(n)$ to $\delta(t)$, and the sum to an integral. But in this case we need deal with the notion of a continuous basis of $L^2$--and a basis of distributions at that! What is the state of formal work in this area and is there an easy entry/reference for someone with basic knowledge of analysis / topology / linear algebra and some knowledge of functional analysis?

Comment: What I've seen were just approximations of vectors $L^{2}$ by linear combinations of a sufficiently large, but finite basis.  More generally, you probably want *dense*, *countable* subsets of the $L^2$ in question.

For example, a signal periodic on an interval $[0, T]$ can be decomposed into its Fourier series.  Then every Fourier sum is a linear combination of the finitely may Fourier basis functions.

Comment: I'm looking for a basis of the form $\{\delta(t-\tau) \ |\  \tau \in R\}$. This is possibly dense but certainly not countable. This is the entire point, as the theory of countable bases is classical. Fourier series works by projecting $R \rightarrow R/TZ$, e.g. the circle group for functions of period $T$, and constructing an eigenseries of the characters $e^{int}$. An interesting (and well trod) topic, but perhaps different than what I am concerned with.

Comment: P.S. I am also aware there are plenty of great countable bases of $L^2$. The specific distributional basis I am interested in has specific physical interpretations, which privilege it in the applications with which I am concerned. The question is specifically about either this basis or a class of bases which include this one.

Comment: sorry if I didn't grasp the goals you are pursuing by looking for a continuous basis.  Could you elaborate on that more?  Namely, what goals do countable bases fail to achieve that you hope to achieve by a continuous analogue of a basis?

Comment: Sure. The distributional basis would help justify and connect time-domain analysis of LTI systems with frequency-domain analysis (whose basis is also continuous and consists of the characters $e^{i\omega t}$). Time-domain stability criteria (e.g. BIBO stability) are completely determined by the impulse response of the LTI system. Physically this is a measure of how much the system is bound to oscillate on its own (you can check out FIR vs IIR filters). I also believe the continuous basis picture provides a simple way to show the LTI equivalence of different stability criteria.

Comment: I see.  Well, I've seen this done with the aid of the Laplace transform (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability#Continuous-time_signals).  The characters here are not group characters (as in the case of Fourier), but "semigroup characters" $e^{st}$ (no imaginary unit).  Mathematicians don't call these a basis, though, but this is a minor point.

A book where I think this is covered is not specifically on telecommunication, but on control systems in general: http://store.doverpublications.com/0486442780.html

Sorry if this is still unhelpful.

Comment: It's no problem @avs :-) I appreciate the discussion and the time everyone takes to answer questions. I'm actually a control theorist, so very familiar with Laplace analysis. In LTI control LTs are completely equivalent to the FT (send $s$ to $i\omega$ and this is the frequency domain for an LTI system). This is why I've never been totally happy with the LT picture for transient analysis --you're already basically in the frequency domain!

Comment: Are we talking about convolution, then?  I.e., the continuous analog of
$$
u(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty u(m)\delta(n-m);
$$
namely, 
$$
u(t) = \sum_{\tau = -\infty}^\infty u(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)?
$$

Comment: @avs: sort of. In your version the basis is still countable, but the elements are continuous. In what I am interested in, we would have 

$$
u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau.
$$

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant: the integral you wrote.  If that will do, that's convolution, and there is some theory associated with it.  To verify certain types of statements involving convolution, one often approximates $\delta(t)$ by a smooth function which is zero outside of a small neighborhood of $t=0$.  The term for such a function is *mollifier* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

If you give some specific statements / hypotheses you'd like to verify, I may be able to be more helpful.

Comment: for what it's worth, the analogous 'reconstruction' is simply that given by @ALB, which you can consider as a sort of expansion in an uncountable basis, and then we want our LTI operator to be interchangeable with our integral, as in [this exposition of the technique of Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function)